# How to use camel-jasypt when deploying to Tomcat

Tags: tomcat7, apache-camel, jasypt

I've integrated the Camel Jasypt component in my Camel application. I've configured the Jasypt bean to use look for the password in an environment variable named SEC:

```
<bean id="jasypt" class="org.apache.camel.component.jasypt.JasyptPropertiesParser">
    <property name="password" value="sysenv:SEC"/>
</bean>
```

This works when deploying locally but leads to problem when deploying the application as a WAR in Tomcat on the production system.

As Tomcat is started and stopped via an init.d script I am not able to pass Environment Variables to Tomcat.

Is there some way to work around this limitation? Do I need to modify any of Tomcat's configuration files?

Comment: You can export the SEC environment variable in you tomcation init script.

Comment: @WillemJiang Thanks, this worked and seems the right way to do. Post this as an answer and I accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can export the SEC environment variable in you tomcation init script.